# WinHTTP is not communicating with local device using IP config

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, winhttprequest

I was trying to communicate using winHTTP for communication with the [device](https://www.stemmer-imaging.com/media/uploads/illumination/14/144021-CCS-LSS-2404-Manual.pdf) using an IP address connected via ethernet cable. The connection and session are happening. However, [winhttpreceiveresponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpreceiveresponse) is always null.  Here is my piece code which I have taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpconnect) and adapted for my device:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <winInet.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "http_dll.h"
DWORD dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
hConnect = NULL,
hRequest = NULL;

int main(void) {

 //Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"HTTP Connection",
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_AUTOMATIC_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

 //Specify an HTTP server. // http://192.168.0.10/info
if (hSession)
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"192.168.0.10",
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_PORT, 0);
    printf("hSession %08x\n", hSession);


if (hSession == NULL)
{
    dwError = GetLastError();
    goto quit;
}


 //Create an HTTP request handle.
if (hConnect)
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", L"/version",
                    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                    WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                    WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

 //Send a request.
if (hRequest)

  bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
      WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
  printf("bResults %08x\n", bResults);


 //End the request.
if (bResults)
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
    printf("bResults %08x\n", bResults);
 //Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
if (bResults)
{
    do
    {
         //Check for available data.
        dwSize = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
            printf("Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                GetLastError());

         //Allocate space for the buffer.
        pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
        if (!pszOutBuffer)
        {
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            dwSize = 0;
        }
        else
        {
             //Read the data.
            ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

            if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                printf("Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
            else
                printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);

             //Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
            delete[] pszOutBuffer;
        }
    } while (dwSize > 0);
}



 //Report any errors.
if (!bResults)
    printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

 //Close any open handles.
if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

quit:



if (dwError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    wprintf(L"Application failed with error: %u\n", dwError);
    return -1;
}

return 0;

}
```

If someone could help if I am making any mistakes.Thanks

Comment: What Error Code does `WinHttpReceiveResponse` return? It seems the server has no response to your request And You may need to contact the device vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by changing the flag WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE to WINHTTP_FLAG_ESCAPE_PERCENT in WinHttpReceiveResponse.

Comment: A quality answer needs to include at least the following: `1` An explanation of the core issue. `2` Rationale for why the proposed solution solves the issue. Both of which are missing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).